# Is there a way to use the max of 2 columns in Excel to populate the sumrange for SUMIFS?

Tags: excel, max, multiple-columns, sumifs

I'm currently using SUMIFS on a range of amounts with criteria 1 & 2 about its dates and 3 & 4 to segment the amounts in the sumrange. The issue is that the amounts could pull from 2 different columns depending on which is larger.

It would like something like this:

```
=SUMIFS(RangeOfMaxAmounts, DateRange, DateCriteria, RangeofMaxAmounts, AmountCriteria)
```

This works on a single column, but I'm trying to avoid using a helper column. I have a feeling it could involve using sumproduct, index/match, row, and/or max formulas, but have not come across a combo that works.

Comment: I believe the short answer is 'no' - you can either use Sumifs with a helper column (because sum_range and criteria_range must both be an actual range not an array), or use Sumproduct.

Comment: tried `IF(sumAmount1>sumAmount2,formula1,formula2)` ?

Comment: @TomSharpe, how would you use sumproduct to achieve this? I figured you would lose the actual values to sum when the max is factored in, but I had hoped index/match or something could have helped there.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer. I've made up some data so I won't be sure that it's answered your question, have a look anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the sumproduct (or in Excel 365, just sum) would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A10>B2:B10,A2:A10,B2:B10)*(C2:C10>=E2)*(C2:C10<=E3))
```

[image]